# Fluent Nhibernate QueryOver with date value expression

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Not sure how to accomplish the date expression in the example below in the last line. A similar query fails to execute. I assume I'll have to use some sort of Projections SqlFunction? Anyone help?

```
Session.QueryOver(() => myobj)
.JoinAlias(() => myobj.Object, () => o1)
.Where(() => myobj.SomeInt > o1.Date.Subtract(someTime).Minutes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to convert your date operations from C# methods into DB Server functions. In case of MS SQL Server, we can use the DATEDIFF function:

[DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, endate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Expecting that your object has a column `Date` so we can create this `ICriterion`

```
DateTime someTime = ...;
var sqlString = " DATEDIFF( mi, ?, [Date]) < {alias}.SomeInt ";
var sql = NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Sql(sqlString
              , someTime
              , NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.DateTime);
```

Having this SQL statement as ICriterion we can adjust your snippet:

```
Session
  .QueryOver(() => myobj)
  .JoinAlias(() => myobj.Object, () => o1)
  .Where(sql); // sql = our ICriterion above
```

*This is just a quick example... starting point how to use NHibernate API to do it... some subquery should be more suitable to avoid using explicit `SomeInt` column name...*

Comment: I've worked your example with an adjustment to your sql string now as " DATEDIFF( mi, ?, {alias}.SomeDate) between {alias}.SomeInt and {alias}.AnotherInt" to fit what I'm working with. My question is in my real code I have several aliases and .SomeDate and .SomeInt are aliases of different types. What would I do to make these assign the correct aliases? Thanks for you help.

Comment: My answer is just a hint to your generic question. Just a know how, starting point - showing the way and power of SqlExpression. Well, try to create a detached `subQuery` of your `o1` returning the result of *DATEDIFF*. In this case `{alias}` will be replaced with the `o1` alias. Next step, add `.Where(Subqueries.PropertyGt("SomeInt", subQuery.DetachedCriteria))`. Find *'subquery'* working example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14080092/1679310